# How many solutions are there for $x_1+x_2+x_3=50$, with the restriction that none of the $x_s$ can be greater than or equal to $20$?

Tags: combinatorics

I know without the restriction, it would just be a stars and bar problem which equals $\binom{52}{2}$, but I don't know how to apply the restriction.

Comment: Mix stars-and-bars as you originally thought with inclusion-exclusion over the events that $x_1\geq 21, x_2\geq 21,$ and  $x_3\geq 21$.  Can you count how many solutions there are where $x_1\geq 21$?

Answer (score 5):

If you were to find the number of positive integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=50$ with no constraints, as you said, the problem would be equivalent to a "stars and bars" problem. But if you impose the restriction of $x_i\lt 20$, or $x_i\le 19$, then if you define the variables $y_1,y_2,y_3$ as $x_i=20-y_i$, you just need to find positive integer solutions $y_1,y_2,y_3$ to the equation
$$(20-y_1)+(20-y_2)+(20-y_3)=50$$
or
$$y_1+y_2+y_3=10$$
and the constraint that $y_i\lt 20$ becomes meaningless, since $y_1+y_2+y_3=10$ already implies that $y_i\lt 10\lt 20$. Thus, we have converted your problem into a typical stars and bars problem. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

I think of these problems as putting $50$ balls in three buckets.  Now put $20$ balls in the first bucket, and count how many ways there are to put the remaining $30$ balls in the three buckets. Of course, we could have put the $20$ balls in any of the three buckets, and we also have to worry about double counting.

Once you've adjsuted for this, you just subtract this number from ${52\choose2}$.